# List of vertical scrollable items which I can drag to left and show two Buttons

Tags: android, scroll, menu, drag, slide

I need to make a list of items inside a `scrollview` (or `RecyclerView`, dunno), which each items has some info, and I can drag to left and remove or choose that item.

How can I do that?

Comment: can you elaborate "I can drag to left and remove or choose that item"

Comment: It's similar a list with "swipe to dismiss", but instead a dismiss, wrap the field and show two buttons when the user press and hold the field, and drag to left

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice library on github which can help you out it shows delete button on right swipe
https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout

Comment: Amazing! That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Diego if this answer your question than please mark it as correct